# Ajax load more posts button

Tags: ajax

I'm trying to use this tutorial but it doesn't work: https://artisansweb.net/load-wordpress-post-ajax/

Correct order is: Post 4, Post 1, Post 3, Post 2. The first 2 posts are OK (before click), but when I click button the results are wrong (Post 2, Post 1 AGAIN) instead of Post 3, Post 2.

This is my code:

PAGE TEMPLATE:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Ajax */
get_header(); ?>

<div class="entry-content">
    <?php 
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'paged' => 1
    );
    $my_posts = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($my_posts->have_posts()) {
    ?>
        <div class="my-posts">
            <?php while ($my_posts->have_posts()) { $my_posts->the_post(); ?>
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <button class="loadmore">Load more...</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";
var page = 2;

jQuery('body').on('click', '.loadmore', function() {
    var data = {
        'action': 'load_posts_by_ajax',
        'page': page,
        'security': '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("load_more_posts"); ?>',
        'all_pages': '<?php echo $my_posts->max_num_pages;  ?>'
    };

    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        jQuery('.my-posts').append(response);
        if(page == data['all_pages']) {
            jQuery('.loadmore').fadeOut(400);
        }
        page++;
    });
});

</script>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

FUNCTIONS:

```
function load_posts_by_ajax_callback() {
    check_ajax_referer('load_more_posts', 'security');
    $paged = $_POST['page'];
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'paged' => $paged
    );
    $my_posts = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($my_posts->have_posts()) {
        while ($my_posts->have_posts()) { $my_posts->the_post(); ?>
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <?php the_excerpt();
        };
    };
    wp_die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_load_posts_by_ajax', 'load_posts_by_ajax_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_posts_by_ajax', 'load_posts_by_ajax_callback');
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1) You should really use a separate JS file.
2) Check this guide: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/

Comment: separate JS file and wp_localize_script didnt help